# Return Results of a Function Within a Variable to Change the Varible

Tags: php, function, variables, switch-statement, vbulletin

I am trying to pass a function into an existing variable to set specific locations within my template.  However when I use the function switch I am not receiving any results.

```
function posicionnavbar($posicion) {
    switch ($posicion) {
        case 'top':
            return 'top';
        case 'soc':
            return 'soc';
        case 'nav':
            return 'nav';
        case 'usr':
            return 'usr';
    }
}
```

And the variable I am attempting to append to.

```
$omni[posicionnavbar($tabs['position'])] .= $nuevo_tab;
```

More Info:

```
$tabs['position']
```

Is either - top, soc, nav, or usr

```
$omni***
```

Is the variable used within my template for each location. IE: `$omnitop`

I have passed the variable using `$omni .= $nuevo_tab;` and using `$omni` within my template to confirm everything was working, with success.  Which lead me to something being off with my function.

How can I pass my function into my variable to change the variable name?

end results would output one of the following:

```
$omnitop .= $nuevo_tab;
$omnisoc .= $nuevo_tab;
$omninav .= $nuevo_tab;
$omniusr .= $nuevo_tab;
```

Comment: Using names like `top`, `soc` sounds like you should be using an array for these instead of different variables.  This is what your existing solution gives you.

Comment: I actually took it a step further and made it even cleaner now knowing the proper way to add a variable to a variable, no array or function needed, just appended my sql result straight to the variable `${'omni'.$tabs['position']} .= $nuevo_tab;`

Comment: "Variable variables" often indicate the the programmer should probably be using arrays to structure related data.

Comment: In the sense I am using this though making the code 21 lines shorter and pulling my variables together directly with the SQL result just seems to make more sense. `${'omni'.$tabs['position']} .= $nuevo_tab;` gives me all I need, without the mess of an array, or switch to do exactly what it is already doing.

Comment: Your coding style is so convoluted that I can only consider this question to be an XY Problem.  If I had a [mcve] and could understand your intent, I would suggest a completely refactored approach.   ...but I can't follow your code or question.  Your `switch()` is poorly designed, it returns the input string at best or nothing at worst (there is no `default` branch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did manage to solve this.

```
${'omni'.posicionnavbar($tabs['position'])} .= $nuevo_tab;
```

thanks to [PHP Cookbook](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch05_05.htm)

Knowing the proper symbols to link the variables together, I got rid of the switch and function altogether. The way I have this set up `${'omni'.$tabs['position']} .= $nuevo_tab;` is enough to get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create an array $omni with keys returned from your function. Then it will be easier to iterate over the results

```
 <?php
        

function posicionnavbar($posicion) {
    switch ($posicion) {
        case 'top':
            return 'top';
        case 'soc':
            return 'soc';
        case 'nav':
            return 'nav';
        case 'usr':
            return 'usr';
    }
}

$tabs['position'] = 'top';
$nuevo_tab = "Something";

$omni[posicionnavbar($tabs['position'])] .= $nuevo_tab;

//let's imagine you got the value of $nuevo_tab here (for simulate the loop)
$omni['soc'] .= "Something related with soc";
$omni['nav'] .= "Something related with nav";    
$omni['usr'] .= "Something related with usr";   

foreach ($omni as $key => $value) {
    echo "\n";
    echo "the key {$key} has the value -> {$value}";
}
```

Anyway, your answer is valid. The one I have proposed is only for convenience. In case in the future you want to access what seem to be variables that are related, with a simple loop